# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VSCODE_TEXTMATE_DEBUG')

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, markdown, nuxt3

I get this error when trying to use shiki in nuxt3. I do not know the cause, I tried adding that environment variable, but it didn't work.

I've recreated the error here https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-whzftm?file=pages%2F%5B...slug%5D.vue